# Not able to access Neo4j server on CentOS VM on Mac

Tags: macos, neo4j, centos

I have a Mac running a CentOS VM. I successfully installed Neo4j and was able to start the server (`[API] Remote interface ready and available at [http://0.0.0.0:5000/]`).

I also uncommented the line `org.neo4j.server.webserver.address=0.0.0.0` in the neo4j-server.properties file. I changed the webserver port from 7474 to 5000 (`org.neo4j.server.webserver.port=5000`) since I know for sure that the port works - as I run Flask web-apps on CentOS and view the UI on Mac by putting `http://<vm-ip-address>:5000/`on Chrome (I made sure the Flask process is stopped and no one is using that port). But this is not working for the Neo4j local server as I keep getting `This webpage is not available` for both 7474 and 5000. Am I missing something ?

Comment: Which VM technology do you using? Docker or classic VM (VirtualBox, VMWare)

Comment: I'm wondering why your are trying to run neo4j on the same port than Flask ?

Comment: did you stop flask before you started neo? are you trying to access the centos vm from the mac? can you access the host / port from the centos vm and not. do you have an aversion to 7474 or did it just not work there to start with?  if no aversion and on centos 7, you can use something like this "firewall-cmd --zone=public --add-port=7474/tcp --permanent" to open up 7474 to your mac.

Comment: I am using VMWare Fusion. I am not running neo4j and Flask on the same port. I turned off the Flask server and checked if 5000 and 7474 were not in use by running `nestat -antup` (anyways, the server won't start if the port is in use). And yes, I am trying to access the server on my centos vm from my mac browser. I ran the command you sent but it won't work (both for 7474 and 5000) :/

Comment: Uhm, is the firewall – which is activated by default – configured correctly? Anyway, the better place to ask would be either http://www.serverfault.com **or** http://dba.stackexchange.com

Comment: So, I don't know the what the problem is with centos - but I started a ssh tunnel `ssh -L 7474:localhost:7474 user@vm`. Now when I enter `http://localhost:7474/` I can see the UI ! It works for now, but maybe there might be some issue with opening the ports on centos? I will talk to our devops team. Thanks everyone for the input !